# If element name is not given in Combobox Itemsource binding, then it display empty combobox

Tags: silverlight

***This is the code snippet:***

```
 setter.Value = (DataTemplate)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(
           @"<DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"" xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml""> 
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment='Left' Height='Auto'  VerticalAlignment='Top' Width='Auto'> 
                <Grid Width='Auto'> <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> <ColumnDefinition Width='80*'/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width='20*'/></Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.Resources><Style TargetType='ComboBoxItem' x:Key='comboboxStyle' > 
                <Setter Property='FlowDirection' Value='LeftToRight'/>
                <Setter Property='Width' Value='" + ColumnWidthList[i] + "' /></Style></Grid.Resources>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column='0'  Text='" + columnName + "' HorizontalAlignment='Left'/>
           <ComboBox MinWidth='16' Grid.Column='1' FlowDirection='RightToLeft' ItemContainerStyle='{StaticResource comboboxStyle}' Name='cmbColors' ItemsSource='{Binding NewLst[" + i + "]}' SelectedItem='{Binding SelectedIt, Mode=TwoWay,ElementName=s1}' SelectedValue='{Binding SelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay,ElementName=s1}' SelectedValuePath='Item1' DisplayMemberPath='Item1'> </ComboBox></Grid></StackPanel></DataTemplate>");
  headerStyle.Setters.Add(setter);
  datagrid1.Columns[i].HeaderStyle = headerStyle;
```

If I give ,ElementName=s1 in this then it works fine

```
ItemsSource='{Binding NewLst[" + i + "],ElementName=s1}
```

Can anyone please suggest how we could use this without the element name?
Element Name is the name of the user control x:name="s1".
As I'm using this code in templated control with the Generic.xaml, there is no user control. So I want to use it without the element name. I'm creating combobox dynamically to display it in the column header of DataGrid

Comment: If you turn that unformatted glob of xaml into something readable I promise to try finding the cause for your issue.

Comment: That's no improvement.